# how to execute TThread with parameter like in windows api?

Tags: c++, c, c++builder

When i creating TThread i can't pass parameters to thread, so i need use global variables or what?
I am using Embarcaderos Rad Studio C++ Builder 2010

Comment: I'm a Delphi guy instead of C++ Builder. In Delphi, you overload the constructor to accept other parameters instead of or with the CreateSuspended bool. It would be the same in Builder. (Posting as a comment instead of an answer because I can't suggest code.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a class derived from TThread, right?  Can you just make your class constructor take additional arguments (beyond the `bool suspended` one that seems to be common)?

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to providing a different constructor is to simply assign properties of the thread between the time you create the object and the time you start it.

```
bool suspended = true;
TSergeyThread* thread = new TSergeyThread(suspended);
thread->Property1 = 4;
thread->SetValue("foo");
thread->Start(); // or ->Resume(), if your VCL is too old
```

Better is to provide all that information in the constructor, though. (RAII, and all that.)